# Zend Framework addaction with success or failure message

Tags: zend-framework

```
public function addAction()
{
    $form = new ApplicationForm();
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
        $name = $form->getvalue('name');                
            $class = $form->getvalue('class');
            $file = new Application_Model_DbTable_Records();
            $file->addRecord($name,$class);
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');    
    } 
    }
}
```

Above addAction controller part, here when i am clicking AddAction my form is waiting for user inputs when i click submit my inputs recorded in database.

Now my question is i want add some message after the submit form data whether it success or failure.

Could you please help me on this ?

Many Thanks,
viswa

Comment: See the [FlashMessenger action-helper](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger)

Comment: could you please give me any example, because i am newly learning zend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs for the action-helper](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger) describe an example. But standard usage goes something like this:

After you add the record, before you redirect, set the desired message in your controller:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $form = new ApplicationForm();
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $name = $form->getValue('name');                
            $class = $form->getValue('class');
            $file = new Application_Model_DbTable_Records();
            $file->addRecord($name,$class);

            // Add the message here
            $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage('Record added');

            $this->_helper->redirector('index');    
       } 
    }
}
```

Then in your `indexAction` - the controller to which you are redirecting after successful record addition - get the messages and add them to your view:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // All your existing processing
    // Blah, blah..

    // Get the messages from the FlashMessenger
    $messenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger'); 
    $messages = $messenger->hasMessages() ? $messenger->getMessages() : [];

    // Add the messages into the view
    $this->view->messages = $messages;
}
```

Finally, somewhere in the index view-script where you want the messages to appear, check for the messages and render, something like:

```
<?php if ($this->messages): ?>
<div id="refresh-messages">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($this->messages as $message): ?>
        <li><?= $message ?></li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

The wrapping div is just to assist with styling by providing a DOM element id to which you can target your CSS.

Disclaimer: Not tested directly, just coding from memory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
i have Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$messenger' (T_VARIABLE) on my controller page line exactly $messages $messenger->hasMessages() ? $messenger->getMessages() : [];

Comment: Hi David kindly help on this

Comment: Might be a PHP version thing. Try replacing `[ ]` with `array()`.

Comment: Still same issue  updated like this;
$messages $messenger->hasMessages() ? $messenger->getMessages() : array();

Comment: Stupid typo in the answer; missing `=` sign. Should be `$messages = $messenger->hasMessages() ? $messenger->getMessages() : [ ];` Editing answer.

Comment: @user6420577: You're welcome. May I suggest that you "Accept" this answer (by clicking the check mark) and upvote it. Welcome to Stack Overflow! :D

Comment: Hi David, Regarding the flash message, how to add css style sheet on this could you please help me ?

Comment: Kind of outside the scope of this question. But, in general, The ZF1 way to add a stylesheet to your page is to have something like `$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/url/for/stylesheet.css')` in the view-script. Then, in the stylesheet itself, you can target the message element using the CSS selector `#refresh-messages`. So, to style the `<li>` elements, you could, for example,  use something like `#refresh-message ul li { color: red; }`.

Comment: Actually i have separate css file example myfile.css then i linked my Form file into that <link id="tabs-css" type="text/css" href="/css/myfile.css" rel="stylesheet" />.

Next inside the myfile.css i added like this #refresh-message ul li { color: red; } but it is not working.

Comment: I think you need `rel="stylesheet"` attribute: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">`.

Comment: I created file theme.css and i included in zend form itself like below 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme/theme.css">